# How to order by multiple columns in pyspark

Tags: sorting, pyspark, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

I have a data frame:-

```
Price   sq.ft   constructed
15000   800     22/12/2019
80000   1200    25/12/2019
90000   1400    15/12/2019
70000   1000    10/11/2019
80000   1300    24/12/2019
15000   950     26/12/2019
```

I want to sort multiple columns at once though I obtained the result I am looking for a better way to do it. Below is my code:-

```
df.select("*",F.row_number().over(
    Window.partitionBy("Price").orderBy(col("Price").desc(),col("constructed").desc())).alias("Value")).display()
Price   sq.ft   constructed Value
15000   950   26/12/2019    1
15000   800   22/12/2019    2
70000   1000    10/11/2019  1
80000   1200    25/12/2019  1
80000   1300    24/12/2019  2
90000   1400    15/12/2019  1
```

Rather than repeating `col("column name").desc()` each time is there any better way to do it?
I have also tried the below way:-

```
df.select("*",F.row_number().over(
    Window.partitionBy("Price").orderBy(["Price","constructed"],ascending = False).alias("Rank"))).display()
```

getting an error:-

```
TypeError: orderBy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ascending'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

Window.partitionBy("Price").orderBy(*[F.desc(c) for c in ["Price","constructed"]])
```